# Angular FormArray Insert

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular4-forms

I am trying to update a specific value on an formArray using  insert(). 
I initialize form on ngOninit() like this:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    exercises: this.fb.array([]),
    type: new FormControl(),
    day: new FormControl(),
    sets: this.fb.array([]),
    reps: this.fb.array([]),
});
```

I have an input where on change i call the below function but when i try to insert a new value with the array's index I get the value pushed.

```
onSetsChange(sets, index){
  var setsFormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.sets;
  setsFormArray.insert(index, new FormControl(sets));
}
```

The html code is below:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="form-control input-sm" (change)="onSetsChange($event.target.value, exerciseIndex)">
     <option *ngFor="let set of sets; let i = index;">{{set}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The **exerciseIndex** I pass is from a loop that it doesn't show up.

What i am doing wrong and the value it's not updating? Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just use two way data binding via `[(ngModel)]` for working with values?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide because FormControls are way more powerful and clear?

Comment: @oMpamparos your problem is not clear. Why do you use index from one array to insert the values **by the same index** into another array? Probably you should transfer your `FormArray` into `FormGroup` if you want to keep the values by the same index

Comment: Yea I am trying to update a Form array's element on click. I am angular newbie and I read that formControls are the best choice to build forms. Any idea why I can't update the array's element?

Comment: @smnbbrv I am trying with the outer index which is the exerciseIndex to update sets array element with the same index from myForm group.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see the practical reasons of that, that's why I won't be able to help. Could you please create a minimal version of a problem as plunkr and describe the problem more precisely?

Comment: @smnbbrv Think that you have a form group that has an attribute sets which is a Form array. You want to update only the sets[1] for example . How will you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `patchValue` :-

```
public ngOnInit() {
    const arr = new FormArray([
                new FormControl(),
                new FormControl()
            ]);

    let control = arr.controls[0];
    setTimeout(() => control.patchValue("new-val"), 250); // Set value to "new-val"
    setTimeout(() => console.log(control.value), 350); // Logs "new-val"
}
```

Comment: I don't want to push the new value. I want to update the old value with the new one.

Comment: So you want to change the FormControl or change the value of the FormControl?

Comment: I want to change the form control value which is inside form array by it's index

Comment: Use patch value? - Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
onSetsChange(sets, index){
    var setsFormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.sets;
    (setsFormArray.at(index)).patchValue(sets);
    console.log(index);
    console.log(setsFormArray);
}
```

this is another solution I figured out. Thank you